OOP Design of a Mathematical Group
A Group is formally defined as a set of Element's,
over which a single operator mul is defined.
There are different kinds of Groups,
and each kind requires a different set of parameters.
Operator mul also depends on the parameters.
I'm trying to design an abstraction of this scenario,
where I can use a generic Group and a generic Element,
thereby hiding the details of the group that I'm using.
So far, I have only managed to model
the one-to-many relation between a group instance and its elements:
class Element {
public:
  Element(Group* group) {
    this->group = group;
  }

private:
  Group* group;
};

class Group {
public:
  virtual Element* mul(Element* a, Element* b) = 0;
};

Let's say my Group has another method, namely exp,
that takes element a and exponent n,
and performs mul(mul(...(a, a)...)) (i.e., a^n).
Is it possible to easily abstract away this method?
My main challenge was dealing with memory (de-)allocation,
as the base Group does not know about
the implementation details of Elements,
and I need to also abstract away a lot of memory management.
I would greatly appreciate your corrections to my design as well.

Can you share the motivation to capture a reference to a Group within an Element?  Is it required that an Element instance be part of only one Group instance?

@ErikEidt Yes, an element should only belong to one group. I'm assuming that I won't have more than one instance of a "particular" group (i.e., of the same type and having the same parameters).

Ok, but we can have different mathematical Groups all based on the (same) set of real numbers, for example. And, why does an Element need to know its Group?

@ErikEidt This is more of a 'wrapping' attempt, to have a single interface for all of my groups; for the groups I'll actually implement, I'll be using primitive types, but for something like an elliptic curve, I need to use interfaces of another library.
An element does not need to know its group, but I wanted to have a way to test whether to elements are in the same group.

Why not make it Element mul(Element a, Element b)? That will probably solve your memory allocation issues.

@DocBrown Now I think it makes sense; maybe pass-by-reference arguments Element& a instead of Element a)?

If I expect Element to hold only one or two integers or double values, I would probably stick with Element mul(Element a, Element b). Otherwise, I would prefer Element mul(const Element &a, const Element &b).

I think you could abandon Element class altogether and leave the element type open by using a class template. It would open up the possibility of defining Groups using existing types for elements.

Consider also not modeling the Group explicitly, and only having the Element class, with the operations mul and exp defined on it (might internally call to some helper function, or consult a table or something). Then for a derivative, a correct implementation would be required to implement mul according to group axioms (associativity, unique identity element, inverse element for every element). This avoids having parallel hierarchies, and would probably make things much easier.

Can we have a class CyclicGroup? And a class GroupProduct?

Why does an element need a group? 20 is an element of Z21, Z22, Z23 etc.

A group is a triple of a set, an associative binary operation, and the identity element of that binary operation, with the requirement that every element have an inverse.
The element of one group is unrelated to the element of another group, so your idea of having base classes Element and Group is nonsensical. It is also nonsensical to say that an element is associated with exactly one group. 1 isn't associated with just multiplication.
What you can do is define a template Group, that has all three as parameters.
template <typename Operation, typename Element>
concept binary_operation = requires std::is_invocable_r_v<Element, Operation, Element, Element>;

// can't check associativity + presence of inverse with concepts, binary_operation is the best we can do here
template <typename Element, binary_operation<Element> Operation, Element Identity>
class Group {
    Operation operation;
public:
    static constexpr Element identity = Identity;
    Element mul(Element lhs, Element rhs) { return operation(lhs, rhs); }
    Element exp(Element value, std::size_t n) { 
        Element result = identity;
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            result = mul(value, result);
        }
        return result;
    }
};

using RealMulGroup = Group<double, std::multiplies<>, 1.0>;
using IntPlusGroup = Group<int, std::plus<>, 0>;

Alternatively you could make Group polymorphic for one kind of element.
template <typename Element>
class Group {
public:
    virtual Element mul(Element lhs, Element rhs) const = 0;
    virtual Element identity() const = 0;

    Element exp(Element value, std::size_t n) { 
        Element result = identity();
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            result = mul(value, result);
        }
        return result;
    }
};

class RealMulGroup : public Group<double> {
public:
    double mul(double lhs, double rhs) const override { return lhs * rhs; }
    double identity() const override { return 1.0; }
};

N.b. I'm not convinced that mul and exp are appropriate names for a general group.

The —> is funny. For about 1500 ms.

Slight nitpick: IntMulGroup isn't a group, but a monoid (not every element has a multiplicative inverse)

@Useless good point

I think the second option is closer to what I need; it clears the need to 'tie' groups and their proper elements together. The first option is good, but it changes my design a bit too much.

I suspect that Element Identity can have =Element{ } as a reasonable default. It works for addition on numeric types, sequence concatenation, and set unions.

@MSalters and it fails for mul, which is what OP named the operation

If your main issue is memory allocation,  and if you absolutely need to use a reference semantic rather than a value semantic, for example because you want Element to be polymorphic,  then just replace the raw pointers with shared pointers:
class Group;  
class Element {
public:
  Element(shared_ptr<Group> group) : group(group) {
  }
private:
  shared_ptr<Group> group;
};

class Group {
public:
  virtual shared_ptr<Element> mul(shared_ptr<Element> a, shared_ptr<Element> b) = 0;
  shared_ptr<Element> exp(shared_ptr<Element> a, unsigned int n) {
    if (n>1) 
        return mul(a, exp(a,n-1)); 
    else return a; 
  }
};

You can then create new elements with make_shared<Element>(...) and get them automatically deleted when the reference count decreases to zero, which will probably happen if you forget to store a mul() result.
This design seems however flawed, because:

the group does not know its elements;
nothing ensures that the elements are homogeneous.  You could for example combine a IntElement with a StringElement.
typically the implementation of mul() depends on the exact type of Element.

A better approach would be to use templates. Here a first demo,  but of course,  not knowing the design constraints, there are certainly things to be refined:
template<class Element>
class Group {
public:
  void add(Element e) {
      set_of_elements.insert(e); // alternatively you could consider that all possible Element values belong to the group
  }
  virtual Element mul(Element a, Element b) = 0;
  Element exp(Element a, unsigned int n) {
    // ideally wwe should start iteration at 0 and the neutral element
    Element res=a; 
    for (int i=1; i<n; i++) 
        res = mul(a, res); 
    return res; 
  }
private: 
  set<Element> set_of_elements; 
};

class MyIntMulGroup : public Group<int> {
public: 
   int mul(int a, int b) override {
      return a*b; 
   }    
}; 

int main() {
    MyIntMulGroup g; 
    cout << g.mul(2,4) << endl; 
    cout << g.exp(2,4) << endl; 
}


I have also switched to using more smart pointers in my implementation. Now, it's much closer to your first answer. I have designed it this way, as I needed to make a plausibly abstract interface for groups and elements; so, for an external user, a group just creates and returns elements that can be operated on; there is no need to know what these elements are (i.e., what data they contain), as long as the group can work with them.
